# Constructor Injection with ServiceStack MVC Powerpack + Funq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack, funq

I'm playing with the demo MVC 3 Internet Application template and I installed the ServiceStack.Host.Mvc NuGet package. I'm having issues with Funq performing constructor injection.

The following snippet is working fine:

```
public class HomeController : ServiceStackController
{
    public ICacheClient CacheClient { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if(CacheClient == null)
        {
            throw new MissingFieldException("ICacheClient");
        }

        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The following throws the error

> Cannot create an instance of an interface.

```
public class HomeController : ServiceStackController
{
    private ICacheClient CacheClient { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index(ICacheClient notWorking)
    {
        // Get an error message...
        if (notWorking == null)
        {
            throw new MissingFieldException("ICacheClient");
        }

        CacheClient = notWorking;

        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

It's not a huge deal since the public property injection works, but I would like to know what I'm missing.

Comment: Where is the constructor? they look the same to me?

Comment: Yeah I botched that one pretty bad... I obviously put the ICacheClient interface in the action method, not the constructor. Thanks @mythz for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note in your 2nd example you don't have a **constructor** but you do have the **method**:

```
public ActionResult Index(ICacheClient notWorking)
{
    ....
}
```

Which won't work only **constructors and public properties** are injected. 
You could change it to:

```
public class HomeController : ServiceStackController
{
    private ICacheClient CacheClient { get; set; }

    public HomeController(ICacheClient whichWillWork)
    {
       CacheClient = whichWillWork;
    }

    ...
}
```